# android webview javascript bridge, why passed in string got resolved to the div element

Tags: android-webview, android-webview-javascript

In webview code it calls into the loaded javascript, passing in the string for the html div element id `"module_1", `<div id="module_1" class="module"></div>`:

```
my_web_view.evaluateJavascript(
     "javascript:sendHtmlMarkerLocation("module_1");", null)
```

and the javascript is to accepting a string for the div element id, and then lookup the div element and get its location:

```
        function sendHtmlMarkerLocation( moduleElementId ) {

            console.log('+++ enter sendHtmlMarkerLocation()'+moduleElementId+', 
                         window.androidObj:'+window.androidObj);

            var elm = null
            var moduleId = moduleElementId
            if (moduleElementId instanceof String) {
                elm = document.getElementById(moduleElementId)
            } else if (moduleElementId instanceof Element) { // how it changes to the div element ???
                elm = moduleElementId 
                moduleId = elm.id
            }

            var _x = 0;
            var _y = 0;
            while( elm && !isNaN( elm.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( elm.offsetTop ) ) {
                _x += elm.offsetLeft - elm.scrollLeft;
                _y += elm.offsetTop - elm.scrollTop;
                elm = elm.offsetParent;
            }
            var width = getWindowWidth()
            var height = getWindowHeight()
            window.androidObj.sendLocationToAndroid(moduleId, _x, _y, width, height);
        }
```

but it crashes since the passed in `moduleElementId` is not the string div id `"module_1"` anymore, instead it is resolved to the `<div id="module_1" class="module"></div>`.

the coresponding console.log is:

```
+++ enter sendHtmlMarkerLocation()[object HTMLDivElement], window.androidObj:function AndroidClass(){} @ 48
```

How it is changed from string id to the `<div>` element?

[image]

Comment: You don't need `javascript:` prefix. That error looks weird. But I think you can solve it in the js side by adding this to the first line of your function: `moduleElementId = moduleElementId.id` since it's a dom element.

Comment: thanks @YunusEmre. trying to see if there is explanation why the passed in string id automatically resolved into the Element with that id.